# Assigning empty string to numpy array element, raises ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, matrix

I'm trying to assign elements of an array through the tkinter entry but I'm not getting it. I'm getting the following error:

```
 line 24, in teste
    matriz[l][c] = elementos.get()
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Code below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("Determinante e Matriz identidade")
janela.geometry("650x500+120+120")
janela.configure(bg='bisque2')

ordem1 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ordem1.grid(row=2, column=4) 

def teste():
    ordem = ordem1.get()
    ordem = int(ordem)

    matriz = np.zeros((ordem,ordem))
    
    for l in range(0, ordem):
        for c in range(0, ordem):  
            elementos = Entry(janela, width=4)
            elementos.grid(row=6+l, column=5+c)

            matriz[l][c] = elementos.get()
            
button = Button(janela, text="Ir", bg="white", command=teste)
button.grid(row=3, column=4)

janela.mainloop()
```

I hope I can complete the elements of the matrix and use a library to calculate the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: What is it that you hoped this code would do?

Comment: before anyone gets the silly idea to make a numpy array holding *strings*, don't. OP clearly needs numbers in there, and just didn't consider that strings don't turn into numbers on their own. -- OP, you need to _convert_ explicitly. and you need to consider what to do about empty Entry boxes.

Comment: @João Alves. Very sorry. I will switch to another computer that will work with numpy. I forgot about numpy.

Comment: @toyotaSupra OK,  the program looks so simple, I just need the input values ​​to go into the array. In my opinion, it makes sense to put matriz[l][c] = elements.get(). But it doesn't work like that

Comment: It worked. But still getting     matriz[l][c] = float(elementos.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: Change brace bracket to square bracket. matriz = np.zeros([ordem,ordem]). Comment out  matriz[l][c] = elementos.get() and replace with print(matriz) in first loop.

Comment: Ok. I getting code working w/out an error. I can see in debug. [[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]

Comment: obviously empty strings need special treatment. empty strings can never be valid numbers. and don't take supra's comments too seriously. round or square brackets don't matter to numpy.

Comment: It is found  an OOP. This is correct way  np.zeros([ordem,ordem])

Comment: numpy **does not care** how you specify a *shape*. they prefer tuples but lists work just fine. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html -- what does "it is found an OOP" mean?

Comment: Don't have a way to number the entry? Type elements[k] = Entry(window, width=4). Because then I made a loop and put matrix[l][i] = elements[k].get()

Comment: I'm lost, I don't understand what to do. Can you do for me the part that takes the inputs and sends them to an matrix and then prints that matrix?